# Sun in between moon and earth , is it possible?

Tags: science-based

Is it possible for sun to come in between earth and moon ?

Like an eclipse when earth comes in between Sun and moon or when moon comes in between sun and earth .

What are conditions for Sun to come in between earth and moon ?

Comment: Please check some basic facts before asking: Sun's diameter is larger than Earth - Moon distance. And how is this about building fictional world?

Comment: Is it possible? No. Never. Not ever. Nope.

Comment: @Mołot "building fictional world" ...do you want every time me to lie ...i am writing a book for posting a question here ?

Comment: No need to write a book, some worlds are built just for fun of building. But if you are not worldbuilding, don't ask on worldbuilding.stackexchange.com. There is astronomy stack site, for example.

Comment: Yes this is "possible". There are many questions about moving planets and such here, check them out. If we moved the moon to the other side of the sun for no reason, that would do the trick I believe. But I'm 99% sure that there are currently no plans to do that, so you will sadly never experience such a lunar eclipse.

Comment: Putting aside the fact that the sun would not fit between the earth and the moon, if it were squeezed in somehow and neither body was vaporized then the moon would become a planet

Comment: Hard to believe there was any research effort at all before this question was asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The diameter of the sun is 1,391,400 km and the moon is an average of 384,400 km away, so it doesn't fit in.

You could ideally do it if the sun becomes a black hole: the sun has a [Schwarzschild radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius) of approximately 3.0 km, but gravitational forces make the system very unstable.

It is more likely that the moon will go beyond the sun, but you need at least $1.7847*10^{20}N$ to get the moon out of the orbit.
I do not think it is possible if not artificially.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the other answers, this is completely impossible for our earth-moon system.

However, you could give your moon a very elliptic orbit and have it go behind the sun. This will cause several side effects (and it would probably make life on earth impossible):

- You would only see your "moon" for a few days every 10+ years (I
  haven't done the math, feel free to correct me).
- Earth's orbit would be heavily affected. The mass of the moon is
  non-negligible, so every passage would throw the Earth off his orbit.
- Tidal effects would probably wreck the surface of our planet.

And, even in those conditions, you would hardly have some spectacular effect when the sun "eclipses" your moon: just a minuscule dot, invisible to the naked eye, disappearing behind a gigantic object a hundred of millions times its volume.

Comment: Arguably this wouldn't be a moon anymore, just crazy planet, but neat idea.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The Sun is 1.3914 million km in diameter, and it's spectacularly massive, containing 99.9% of the mass of the solar system.

Everything in the solar system moves relative to the Sun, the Earth **cannot** keep on it's current track while the Sun moves to intercept the earth.

If the Sun were to be influenced by a passing black-hole, the earth would also be influenced and pulled along with the Sun.

Also consider Mercury is 57.9 million kilometers from the Sun, if we were to pass even this close to the Sun it would mean the stripping of our atmosphere and the end of all life on the planet, long before we got that close.

Also the distance between the earth and the moon is 0.38 million kilometers, which is roughly one third of the width of the Sun, so the Sun literally cannot fit between the moon and earth.

So for many many reasons, no this can't work.